# How to delete specific values from a nested dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a nested dictionary, **dict1** as follows:

```
      {'pic1': {'filename': 'pic1.png',
      'size': 545,
      'regions': [{'shape_attributes': {'name': 'polygon',
      'x_values': [211, 205, 214, 232, 254, 263, 265, 265, 263, 257, 221],
      'y_values': [186, 200, 214, 218, 214, 204, 198, 190, 187, 181, 180]},
      'type': {'animal': '1'}},
      {'shape_attributes': {'name': 'polygon',
      'x_values': [272, 266, 275, 293, 315, 324, 326, 326, 324, 318, 282],
      'y_values': [233, 247, 261, 265, 261, 251, 245, 237, 234, 228, 227]},
      'type': {'animal': '2'}},
      {'shape_attributes': {'name': 'polygon',
      'x_values': [366, 360, 369, 387, 409, 418, 420, 420, 418, 412, 376],
      'y_values': [315, 329, 343, 347, 343, 333, 327, 319, 316, 310, 309]},
      'type': {'animal': '2'}},
      {'shape_attributes': {'name': 'polygon',
      'x_values': [201, 195, 204, 222, 244, 253, 255, 255, 253, 247, 211],
      'y_values': [224, 238, 252, 256, 252, 242, 236, 228, 225, 219, 218]},
      'type': {'animal': '3'}}],
      'file_attributes': {}},
      'pic2': {'filename': 'pic2.png',
      'size': 456,
      'regions': [{'shape_attributes': {'name': 'polygon',
      'x_values': [211, 205, 214, 232, 254, 263, 265, 265, 263, 257, 221],
      'y_values': [186, 200, 214, 218, 214, 204, 198, 190, 187, 181, 180]},
      'type': {'animal': '1'}},
      {'shape_attributes': {'name': 'polygon',
      'x_values': [272, 266, 275, 293, 315, 324, 326, 326, 324, 318, 282],
      'y_values': [233, 247, 261, 265, 261, 251, 245, 237, 234, 228, 227]},
      'type': {'animal': '2'}},
      {'shape_attributes': {'name': 'polygon',
      'x_values': [366, 360, 369, 387, 409, 418, 420, 420, 418, 412, 376],
      'y_values': [315, 329, 343, 347, 343, 333, 327, 319, 316, 310, 309]},
      'type': {'animal': '2'}},
      {'shape_attributes': {'name': 'polygon',
      'x_values': [201, 195, 204, 222, 244, 253, 255, 255, 253, 247, 211],
      'y_values': [224, 238, 252, 256, 252, 242, 236, 228, 225, 219, 218]},
      'type': {'animal': '3'}}],
      'file_attributes': {}}}
```

I want to check if any of the x_values or y_values is greater than 500. If it is greater than 500, i have to remove it from the dictionary.For example suppose,

```
    {'shape_attributes': {'name': 'polygon',
    'x_values': [366, 360, 369, 387, 409, 418, 420, 420, 418, 412, 376],
    'y_values': [315, 329, 343, 347, 343, 333, 327, 319, 316, 310, 309]},
    'type': {'animal': '2'}}`
```

If this key value pair meet the above condition, the whole of these should be removed from the dictionary.

Can anyone help me out! Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

This will work:

```
for key in dict1.keys():
    dict1[key]['regions'] = [value for value in dict1[key]['regions'] if
                               (max(value['shape_attributes']['x_values'])<=500)
                               and (max(value['shape_attributes']['y_values'])<=500)]
```

Since you don't have a value greater than 500 currently, nothing will be sorted out.

Comment: Any reason for using bitwise `&` operator rather than logical `and`? Seems like `and` makes more sense from a code readability point of view (since they arcually are logical values), and provides short circuit evaluation which is a benefit here.

Comment: No specific reason for using `&`, question of code style I suppose

Comment: @user34: Works fine for me. Make sure you initiate `orig_dict` as edited above (you had a syntax error there). Then you're fine.

Comment: I think it's worth changing in your answer since this seems to be a new Python user and that's a bad habit to get into. Aside from the two reasons I gave, it also doesn't work properly for truthy and falsey values e.g. `True and [3, 4]` is `True` but `True & [3, 4]` raises a `TypeError` exception.

Answer (score 1):

This solution recursively descends down the passed object. When the object is a list, it recursively descends down each list item and if it is reported back that the searched for item to be removed has been found, then it is removed from the list. When the object is a dictionary, it is tested to see if it has the key 'shape_attributes'. If so, then further testing is done to see if this dictionary should be removed from its parent list and it should, True will be returned back. Otherwise, we recursively descend down the dictionary's values.

```
from itertools import chain

def search_and_remove(o):
    if isinstance(o, list):
        for i, x in enumerate(o):
            if search_and_remove(x):
                del o[i]
        return False
    elif isinstance(o, dict):
        if 'shape_attributes' in o:
            d = o['shape_attributes']
            return any(map(lambda n: n > 500, chain(d['x_values'], d['y_values'])))
        else:
            for v in o.values():
                search_and_remove(v)
            return False

d =   {'pic1': {'filename': 'pic1.png',
      'size': 545,
      'regions': [{'shape_attributes': {'name': 'polygon',
      'x_values': [211, 205, 214, 232, 254, 263, 265, 265, 263, 257, 221],
      'y_values': [186, 200, 214, 218, 214, 204, 198, 190, 187, 181, 180]},
      'type': {'animal': '1'}},
      {'shape_attributes': {'name': 'polygon',
      'x_values': [272, 266, 275, 293, 315, 324, 326, 326, 324, 318, 282],
      'y_values': [233, 247, 261, 265, 261, 251, 245, 237, 234, 228, 227]},
      'type': {'animal': '2'}},
      {'shape_attributes': {'name': 'polygon',
      'x_values': [366, 360, 369, 387, 409, 418, 420, 420, 418, 412, 376],
      'y_values': [315, 329, 343, 347, 343, 333, 327, 319, 316, 310, 309]},
      'type': {'animal': '2'}},
      {'shape_attributes': {'name': 'polygon',
      'x_values': [201, 195, 204, 222, 244, 253, 255, 255, 253, 247, 211],
      'y_values': [224, 238, 252, 256, 252, 242, 236, 228, 225, 219, 218]},
      'type': {'animal': '3'}}],
      'file_attributes': {}},
      'pic2': {'filename': 'pic2.png',
      'size': 456,
      'regions': [{'shape_attributes': {'name': 'polygon',
      'x_values': [211, 205, 214, 232, 254, 263, 265, 265, 263, 257, 221],
      'y_values': [186, 200, 214, 218, 214, 204, 198, 190, 187, 181, 180]},
      'type': {'animal': '1'}},
      {'shape_attributes': {'name': 'polygon',
      'x_values': [272, 266, 275, 293, 315, 324, 326, 326, 324, 318, 282],
      'y_values': [233, 247, 261, 265, 261, 251, 245, 237, 234, 228, 227]},
      'type': {'animal': '2'}},
      {'shape_attributes': {'name': 'polygon',
      'x_values': [366, 360, 369, 387, 409, 418, 420, 420, 418, 412, 376],
      'y_values': [315, 329, 343, 347, 343, 333, 327, 319, 316, 310, 309]},
      'type': {'animal': '2'}},
      {'shape_attributes': {'name': 'polygon',
      'x_values': [201, 195, 204, 222, 244, 253, 255, 255, 253, 247, 211],
      'y_values': [224, 238, 252, 256, 252, 242, 236, 228, 225, 219, 218]},
      'type': {'animal': '3'}}],
      'file_attributes': {}}}

search_and_remove(d)
print(d)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use recursion:

```
data = {'pic1': {'filename': 'pic1.png', 'size': 545, 'regions': [{'shape_attributes': {'name': 'polygon', 'x_values': [211, 205, 214, 232, 254, 263, 265, 265, 263, 257, 221], 'y_values': [186, 200, 214, 218, 214, 204, 198, 190, 187, 181, 180]}, 'type': {'animal': '1'}}, {'shape_attributes': {'name': 'polygon', 'x_values': [272, 266, 275, 293, 315, 324, 326, 326, 324, 318, 282], 'y_values': [233, 247, 261, 265, 261, 251, 245, 237, 234, 228, 227]}, 'type': {'animal': '2'}}, {'shape_attributes': {'name': 'polygon', 'x_values': [366, 360, 369, 387, 409, 418, 420, 420, 418, 412, 376], 'y_values': [315, 329, 343, 347, 343, 333, 327, 319, 316, 310, 309]}, 'type': {'animal': '2'}}, {'shape_attributes': {'name': 'polygon', 'x_values': [201, 195, 204, 222, 244, 253, 255, 255, 253, 247, 211], 'y_values': [224, 238, 252, 256, 252, 242, 236, 228, 225, 219, 218]}, 'type': {'animal': '3'}}], 'file_attributes': {}}, 'pic2': {'filename': 'pic2.png', 'size': 456, 'regions': [{'shape_attributes': {'name': 'polygon', 'x_values': [211, 205, 214, 232, 254, 263, 265, 265, 263, 257, 221], 'y_values': [186, 200, 214, 218, 214, 204, 198, 190, 187, 181, 180]}, 'type': {'animal': '1'}}, {'shape_attributes': {'name': 'polygon', 'x_values': [272, 266, 275, 293, 315, 324, 326, 326, 324, 318, 282], 'y_values': [233, 247, 261, 265, 261, 251, 245, 237, 234, 228, 227]}, 'type': {'animal': '2'}}, {'shape_attributes': {'name': 'polygon', 'x_values': [366, 360, 369, 387, 409, 418, 420, 420, 418, 412, 376], 'y_values': [315, 329, 343, 347, 343, 333, 327, 319, 316, 310, 309]}, 'type': {'animal': '2'}}, {'shape_attributes': {'name': 'polygon', 'x_values': [201, 195, 204, 222, 244, 253, 255, 255, 253, 247, 211], 'y_values': [224, 238, 252, 256, 252, 242, 236, 228, 225, 219, 218]}, 'type': {'animal': '3'}}], 'file_attributes': {}}}
def valid(v):
  return not isinstance(v, list) or all(i < 500 for i in v if not isinstance(i, (dict, list)))

def r_dict(d):
  if isinstance(d, list):
     return [r_dict(i) if isinstance(i, dict) else i for i in d]
  return {a:r_dict(b) if isinstance(b, dict) else b for a, b in d.items() if valid(b)}

result = r_dict(data)
```

Output:

```
{'pic1': {'filename': 'pic1.png', 'size': 545, 'regions': [{'shape_attributes': {'name': 'polygon', 'x_values': [211, 205, 214, 232, 254, 263, 265, 265, 263, 257, 221], 'y_values': [186, 200, 214, 218, 214, 204, 198, 190, 187, 181, 180]}, 'type': {'animal': '1'}}, {'shape_attributes': {'name': 'polygon', 'x_values': [272, 266, 275, 293, 315, 324, 326, 326, 324, 318, 282], 'y_values': [233, 247, 261, 265, 261, 251, 245, 237, 234, 228, 227]}, 'type': {'animal': '2'}}, {'shape_attributes': {'name': 'polygon', 'x_values': [366, 360, 369, 387, 409, 418, 420, 420, 418, 412, 376], 'y_values': [315, 329, 343, 347, 343, 333, 327, 319, 316, 310, 309]}, 'type': {'animal': '2'}}, {'shape_attributes': {'name': 'polygon', 'x_values': [201, 195, 204, 222, 244, 253, 255, 255, 253, 247, 211], 'y_values': [224, 238, 252, 256, 252, 242, 236, 228, 225, 219, 218]}, 'type': {'animal': '3'}}], 'file_attributes': {}}, 'pic2': {'filename': 'pic2.png', 'size': 456, 'regions': [{'shape_attributes': {'name': 'polygon', 'x_values': [211, 205, 214, 232, 254, 263, 265, 265, 263, 257, 221], 'y_values': [186, 200, 214, 218, 214, 204, 198, 190, 187, 181, 180]}, 'type': {'animal': '1'}}, {'shape_attributes': {'name': 'polygon', 'x_values': [272, 266, 275, 293, 315, 324, 326, 326, 324, 318, 282], 'y_values': [233, 247, 261, 265, 261, 251, 245, 237, 234, 228, 227]}, 'type': {'animal': '2'}}, {'shape_attributes': {'name': 'polygon', 'x_values': [366, 360, 369, 387, 409, 418, 420, 420, 418, 412, 376], 'y_values': [315, 329, 343, 347, 343, 333, 327, 319, 316, 310, 309]}, 'type': {'animal': '2'}}, {'shape_attributes': {'name': 'polygon', 'x_values': [201, 195, 204, 222, 244, 253, 255, 255, 253, 247, 211], 'y_values': [224, 238, 252, 256, 252, 242, 236, 228, 225, 219, 218]}, 'type': {'animal': '3'}}], 'file_attributes': {}}}
```